# How to subtract const from the file in awk?

Tags: awk

How can I sub 1 from each element from my txt file. I had actually tried similar to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107652/how-to-subtract-a-constant-value-from-a-data-file) question but was not successes full.

Suppose I have file in the following format

```
2,4,5
1,2,3
14,12,1
```

Now I want the file to be

```
// basically subtract 1 from all 
1,3,4
0,1,2  
13,11,0
```

What I have tried so far is

```
$awk '{if(getline != 0){
          for(i = 0; i <=NF; i++){
              $(i)=$(i)-1;
          }
       } print;}}'
```

I was trying to read till end of file and sub 1 from each element, but when I do this I just -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is right - but you've made a couple of errors:

```
awk -vOFS=, -F, '{
      for(i = 1; i <=NF; i++ ){
          $i -= 1;
      }
      print;
   }' file.txt
```

- `getline` (as you've used it) reads the next line into `$0` - it doesn't make sense here.
- You need to tell awk to split (`FS` or using `-F`) on a comma, by default it will split on whitespace
- `$0` is the whole line so you want to start your loop at `i = 1`
- If you want to print commas on the output you need to set `OFS=,` (output field separator).

Alternatively you can use perl:

```
perl -ple 's{(\d+)}{$1 - 1}eg;' file.txt
```